# Is it true that after offering Gaya Shraddha, the annual Shraddha ceremony need not be done any more?

Tags: sraddha, gaya

I recall hearing this from several people.

Comment: No. Velukkudi swamin explicitly answers this question in his enpani podcast. Annual sraddha is annual. gaya sraddha is once in lifetime. obeying parents is throughout lifetime. these are 3 duties of a son per shastras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radhe Radhe,

I have heard from my Pujya Gurudev Maharaj and Brahmins that doing Gaya shraddha is something one must do for one's ancestor, but it does not end annual shraddha.

Here is a statement by Puri Shankaracharya on this subject- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAerrEbsJhA

**Here it is explained how, according to scriptures (video contains scriptural reference), the annual shraddha has to be continued under all conditions & info about Gaya Shraddha and when Pinda dhaan is not needed - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pmc41fzpsU**

*** I highly recommend everyone watch the second video, especially around 9 minutes. It tells you golden information about Tirtha and Shraddha.*** **Please don't watch only 9 minutes onwards. Watch full, I am telling, as I believe full video length is required to comprehend this knowledge.**

I know people who were led to believe that after Gaya shraddha, they do not need to perform any more shraddha, but their ancestors came to haunt them, and they restarted doing shraddha.

The opinion of my Pujya Gurudev Maharaj, educated Brahmins I know, and the highest authority of Hinduism, Pujya Puri Peeth Shankaracharya, is that annual shraddha is mandatory.

Radhe Radhe,

Hopefully, that answers your question. Forgive me if I have made any mistake or confused you.

Comment: this is good authority.  a scriptural reference would help also. @shyamsharan

Comment: @SK done. I added a video with a reference that explains in detail why it must be done and more extra info about Gaya Shraddha.

Radhe Radhe,

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

जीवतो वाक्यकरणात् प्रत्यब्दम् भूरिभोजनात्
गयायाम् पिण्डदानात् च त्रिभिः पुत्रस्य पुत्रता

The three acts by which a son earns his 'son-ness'

- Obediance when the parents are alive
- Feeding well every year (annual death anniversary)
- Offering oblations to the manes at Gaya

From above verse it is clear that all the three are compulsory duties of the son. Doing one doesn't make another unnecessary or optional. In particular the word प्रत्यब्दम् indicates that it has to be done every year.