# Is it true that Gaya sraadha is equivalent to performing 60 annual sraadhas?

Tags: sraddha, gaya

https://trsiyengar.com/srardha-dharma-tharpana-niyama-faq/

> 1. Gaya sraadha is equivalent to performing 60 annual sraadhas.

If this is true, for someone 30 or 40 years old, it is unlikely that a regular shraddha would come due after Gaya Shraddha.

Is this backed by scripture?

NOTE: not a duplicate of

[Is it true that after offering Gaya Shraddha, the annual Shraddha ceremony need not be done any more?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/56176/12489)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that after offering Gaya Shraddha, the annual Shraddha ceremony need not be done any more?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56176/is-it-true-that-after-offering-gaya-shraddha-the-annual-shraddha-ceremony-need)